# Get index size on each shard?

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, sharding

I have a compound index on a sharded cluster living on Mongo Atlas. The Atlas UI tells me the index size is `10.1GB`. Similarly,

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.myCollection.stats().indexSizes
{
    "_id_" : 14387392512,
    "my_index" : 10810015744
}
```

My cluster has two shards. Can I assume that there is actually 5GB of index on each shard, since each shard contains its own indexing? Is there a way to get the exact size of the index on each shard? If I add a third shard, will this index size be reduced to ~3.3GB per shard, assuming a balanced distribution?

I want to ensure that my index size + working set remains in RAM and find the right balance of vertical scaling (upgrading cluster tiers) vs. horizontal scaling (adding more shards) to accommodate this.

Comment: If you want to figure this out, most effective strategy would be to setup a decent-sized local deployment where you have access to individual shards. If you don't want to do this I would inquire through official MongoDB support channels.

Comment: Can you connect directly to a node in each shard and get the stats?

Answer (score 0):

You are on correct path. Once collection is sharded the `db.stats()` will give stats of entire database and each shard documents/size/indexe size/total size and other things. We have created a report based on this to show daily shard distribution. This in python gives dictionary and easy to get values